# What type of format is this API response?

Tags: api, format

I am using an API that gives me response in this format :

{'captchaId': '11655487', 'code': '644SD843ADSH48678 (just some letters and numbers)'}

Looks like JSON but it uses different quotes.
Does anyone know what format is it??